# Уязвимость стека при реализации через массив Java

Tags: java, массивы, стек, уязвимости

Уважаемы помогите понять какую проблему видит автор при использовании такого стека ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Stack.java**

```
public class Stack {
    int stk[] = new int[10];
    int tos;
    Stack(){
        tos = -1;
    }
    void push(int item){
        if(tos == 9) System.out.println("Стек заполнен!");
        else stk[++tos] = item;
    }

    int pop(){
        if( tos < 0){
            System.out.println("Стек не загружен!");
            return  0;
        }
        else return stk[tos--];
    }
}
```

**StackTest.java**

```
public class StackTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack mystak1 = new Stack();
        Stack mystak2 = new Stack();

        // разместить числа в стеке
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) mystak1.push(i);
        for (int i = 10; i < 20; i ++) mystak2.push(i);

        // извлечь эти числа из стека
        System.out.println("Содержимое первого стека mystack1");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) System.out.println(mystak1.pop());

        System.out.println("Содержимое первого стека mystack2");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) System.out.println(mystak2.pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: он же написал, что в следующей главе всё поправит. Посмотрите её

Comment: думаю, речь о том, что в этой реализации совершенно необязательно пользоваться методами push и pop. Можно напрямую зловредничать в массиве

Comment: Думаю тут вы правы. ну видимо да так как тут поля не приватные...